# How in redux-api-middleware add authentication header

Tags: api, reactjs, redux, middleware

**Action**

```
import { CALL_API } from 'redux-api-middleware';

export const MOVIES_GET_SUCCESS = 'MOVIES_GET_SUCCESS';

export const getMovies = () => {
  return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      endpoint: 'http://localhost:3005/api/movies',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      types: ['REQUEST', MOVIES_GET_SUCCESS, 'FAILURE']
    }
  };
};
```

**Middleware**

```
import { CALL_API } from 'redux-api-middleware';

export default store => next => action => {
  const callApi = action[CALL_API];
  console.log(callApi); // I ALWAYS have undefined 

  if (callApi) {
    callApi.headers = Object.assign({}, callApi.headers, {
      authorization: store.signIn.get('token') || ''
    });
  }

  return next(action);
};
```

**store**

```
export default function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
   // Middleware and store enhancers
  const enhancers = [
    applyMiddleware(apiMiddleware, authorizationMiddleware),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : (f) => {
      return f;
    }
  ];

  return createStore(reducers, initialState, compose(...enhancers));
}
```

i found the solution [here](https://gist.github.com/benpickles/b465db90ca11adc9ea00), But it does not work for me, I need set authorization header for request in my middleware. How to implement it? What's happen wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { apiMiddleware } from 'redux-api-middleware';
import reducers from '../reducers';
import authorizationMiddleware from '../authorizationMiddleware/authorizationMiddleware';

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
   // Middleware and store enhancers
  const enhancers = [
    applyMiddleware(authorizationMiddleware, apiMiddleware),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : (f) => {
      return f;
    }
  ];

  return createStore(reducers, initialState, compose(...enhancers));
}
```

solved, trouble was because I type my middleware after redux-api-middleware, own middleware must be before.